# Negative correlation in image cryptography

Tags: encryption

I am working on an algorithm to encrypt images and I am getting a negative correlation between the encrypted image and the original image. Ideally correlation should be zero but what should I infer from a negative value?

Comment: This can't be answered correctly without some more details.  You use the singular - one pair of images?  We could do with number of images, and the actual numeric correlation(s).  One discrete value is worthless analytically.   A successfully encrypted image will appear as random noise, and anything random can only be assessed statistically.  That requires several /many samples.

Comment: Why create a specialized image encryption algorithm? You could just encrypt the file with standard crypto (preferably authenticated encryption) or the pixels with length-preserving-encryption.

Answer (score 1):

A negative [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) simply implies that your encrypted image resembles the [negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_(photography)) of the original image more than one would expect if the two images were completely unrelated.

Of course, the measured correlation between any two random sets of data is rarely if ever *exactly* zero, even if the values are actually completely independent.  However, if the correlation appears consistently and/or is large enough (in absolute magnitude) to be considered [statistically significant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance), it indicates that your encryption scheme leaks information about the original image, and is therefore not secure.

(Also, note that zero correlation between the original and the encrypted image is *not*, by itself, sufficient to demonstrate security.  For example, an encryption scheme that simply inverted the colors of every second pixel in the image would achieve very close to a zero correlation for most typical images, but would be trivially easy for anyone to decrypt.)

Comment: @PaulUszak: Perhaps you're confusing correlation between the original and the encrypted image (as mentioned by the OP) with *auto*correlation of the encrypted image with itself? In my example, exactly half of the pixels would have a huge positive correlation between the two images (being identical in both), while the other half would have an approximately equally huge *negative* correlation (being inverted). For most images, the two huge correlations of opposite sign will average out to something pretty close to zero. Feel free to test it yourself, if you still don't believe me.